# Apache spark in cluster mode where to run the jobs. In Master or in worker node?

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I have installed the spark in cluster mode. 1 master and 2 workers.And When I start spark shell in master node it is countinously running without getting the scala shell.
But when I run spark-shell on a worker node I am getting scala shell.And I am able to do the jobs.

```
val file=sc.textFile(“hdfs://192.168.1.20:9000/user/1gbdata”)
file.count()
```

And for this I got the output.

So My doubt is actually where to run the spark jobs.
Is it in worker nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#connecting-an-application-to-the-cluster), you need to connect your `spark-shell` to the master node with the following command : `spark-shell --master spark://IP:PORT`. This url can be retrieved from the master's UI or log file.

You should be able to launch the spark-shell on the master node (machine), make sure to check out the UI to see if the `spark-shell` is effectively running and that the prompt is shown (you might need to press enter on your keyboard after issuing spark-shell).

Please note that when you are using `spark-submit` in `cluster` mode, the driver will be submitted directly from one of the worker nodes, contrary to `client` mode where it will run as a client process. Refer to the documentation for more details.